# Just link answers must be flag?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

Today I [flag this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2002010/2887133) as a Just link answer and was declined with this comment:

> declined - Downvote, comment, edit... then flag.

On the past I have flagged more answers as Just Link [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27623514/2887133) that was consider helpfull.

That make sense ?  I know that already are more posts like this on meta and comments arguing that mods are humans, but that behavior on similar answers just tempt me and maybe other users to avoid the flag of answers since I don't know what can happen.

Can someone clarify wich is the right process to handle this kind of answers is really the `Downvote, comment, edit... then flag` the right way? and needed in case that the answer is very old too?

**Edit**

Thinking about the process the mod suggest:

- Downvote : Can create a conflict since the link it's helpfull and doesn't mean the link on the answer isn't useful just have low quality for the standards on the site.
- Comment : Always I make a comment asking for improve but if the answer is too old ? I don't think this can be a requisite to flag.
- Edit : Just seems invalid

Comment: That answer is not quite link-only, even if the link itself is a prominent part of it. Downvote-worthy? Guess so.

Comment: @Deduplicator I think an answer can be marked as Just-link .... if you remove the link then the answer cames very low quality and doesn't provide enough info to solve the issue, once I read that *we want complete answers here that avoids get off-site*

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: It doesn't help that you custom-flagged another answer as "Low quality" that wasn't a problematic answer *at all*.

Comment: @BoltClock You mean this that I flag too http://stackoverflow.com/a/2000602/2887133 ? Isn't that more a comment ? Provide an answer?

Comment: Yes, that one. Even if you don't like short answers, what's so wrong with it that it absolutely requires moderator attention?

Comment: The question asks "Is it possible?" and the answer says "No it's not." If that isn't an answer, what is?

Comment: Ok declined as *flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer* ..... i'm flaggin as low quality not wrong answer .... for me looks like a comment not like an answer. But you are right my miss since the question itself is like that.

Comment: Thanks @gnat seems to me that is better never flag an answer as low quality since mods thinks I flag as wrong, or just-link since is vague the definiton. Just keep with the thanks or I have this problem too.

Comment: to a certain extent that's correct. If one wants to stay on a 100% safe flagging, sticking with thanks and have-this-problem kind "answers" are the way to go. Flagging link-only answers is more complicated and risky

Answer (score 2):

First, that answer isn't strictly link-only. There is small amount of other information. It's not a *great* answer, but it's not the kind of thing we should just delete without taking other steps first.

> Downvote : Can create a conflict since the link it's helpfull and doesn't mean the link on the answer isn't useful just have low quality for the standards on the site.

If an answer is of such quality that you don't even want to downvote it, what are you asking a moderator to do? Presumably delete it, which is more extreme than just downvoting.

> Comment : Always I make a comment asking for improve but if the answer is too old ? I don't think this can be a requisite to flag.

Commenting isn't required before a flag, but it is something you could have done yourself to try and get the answer improved before flagging it. I don't see any comments on that answer asking for the OP to improve it. That's a step anyone can take before asking for a post to simply be deleted.

> Edit : Just seems invalid

How is that invalid? The link still works, so anyone can edit the answer to improve it.

I suggested "Downvote, comment, edit... then flag." not because that's the *only* process that should be followed before flagging a link-only answer, but because *none* of these things had been done when I processed the flag.